# How do I create buttons on the toolbar to increase and decrease font size?

Tags: gvim, font

Many systems offer + and - zoom buttons. Can someone please demonstrate how such two buttons can be emulated with `gvim`?

This means that clicking the + button would increase the font size by one step.
The - button does just the opposite.

Comment: Start with `:h toolbar-icon` and `:h guifont`

Comment: ... and combine with http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_font_size_quickly (I'm lazy, ... I don't need it :D )

Comment: Thanks! I tried, at least with the vim.wikia link. The defined commands seem to be ignored in my gvim, so I am still working on it.

Comment: I think the `pattern` definition has an extra space which will not work on Windows, or in OSes where `guifont` looks like `FontName:h12` instead of `FontName\ 12`. And of course try without the `has("gui_gtk2")` check  (at least for Windows).

Comment: Not sure what to make of this. I am an Ubuntu user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think something along the following lines should work:

```
anoremenu ToolBar.Builtin#31   :let &guifont=substitute(&guifont, '\(\d\+\)', '\=submatch(1)+1', '')<cr>
anoremenu ToolBar.Builtin#32   :let &guifont=substitute(&guifont, '\(\d\+\)', '\=submatch(1)-1', '')<cr>
```

Now, to include nice icons, you simply need to add the icon argument.

Comment: This did not work for me. I got the blurry icons, but clicking these makes the screen refresh without doing anything. I still have to change the font size manually.

Comment: Try `:echo substitute(&guifont, '\(\d\+\)', '\=submatch(1)-1', '')` what does that give you

Comment: Nothing happens. Not sure there was even a refresh.

Comment: You should see an output. What is your guifont setting?

Comment: Oops, now I get it: `Monospace 20`, the command above prints `Monospace 19`

Comment: that looks correct. And if you run this command: `:let &guifont=substitute(&guifont, '\(\d\+\)', '\=submatch(1)-1', '')` Does that decrease your font size?

Comment: Yes, it does, but not in the GUI. Any help here?

Comment: What do you mean, not in the GUI? Please be very specific. Perhaps you have a typo somewhere?

Comment: I copied what you had in your answer to my .vimrc. When I start GVIM, I see the buttons, but they do not do anything. If I type what you gave in the the ":" prompt, it works. Could it be the <CR>?